# Netflix auto play - makes my user log off

Tags: video, streaming, logout, netflix, autoplay

I'm using 14.04. When I'm watching Netflix and it automatically goes to the next episode, my laptop logs off of my user account. So it goes to the screen that you have to enter your password when you're booting up your computer. It also keeps playing the episode - the sound is still coming out and everything, but it's not on the screen because it's just at the log in screen for the computer. It's very annoying to have to get up and log back into my user account every time.

Answer (score 0):

In system settings, click on "Brightness and Lock", then turn off the LOCK toggle switch.

It's locking because the video comes out of fullscreen for a second while switching episodes, and sets off the timer to automatically lock the screen.

Long explanation : Normally auto lock is prevented while playing fullscreen videos, but it seems the timer is still running, and as soon as the video comes out of fullscreen, the timer comes into effect (which has been running the whole time).  I think this is a bug, because in my opinion, the timer should only start after the fullscreen exits, and not based on the last user input.

Comment: Glad to help out!  I had a similar issue before.  Don't forget to accept my answer ;)